# How to view a log file realtime (similar to "tail -f") via web

Tags: web-server, web-applications

I have a server that runs a number of tasks.  Each task has a log file.  I have a webserver that lets you see these log files, but it just copies the contents of the file to the browser and the user has to press F5 over & over...

Is there a way to produce a clean scrolling "live" view for a specified log?  Similar to "tail -f" in the terminal window.

Answer (score 1):

That's possible, but possibly quite impractical if the logs are filling rapidly. This would require

- a script that keeps track of a log file.

  - It could check if the file has changed after the last check and possibly how much it has increased.
  - Then it should get the data from the end of the file: the increased bytes or sufficient amount of lines to compare what's new. That depends on whether it's ok to skip some lines here and there or not, and might be a lot trickier than just `tail -f`.
  - A constantly running `tail -f` might be a source for the script, but that might be a bad design: the buffer might get huge, or be flushed by other users.
  - The script would output the file in e.g. JSON format.
- a JavaScript that

  - calls the previous script regularly and
  - adds the new lines into an element on the web page.
  - Possibly adding the lines above the previous lines would be better suitable for web?

There might be such work or part of it done, if you Google for `log`, `tail` & `AJAX`. I don't know of the quality of those projects, and most seem quite old and unmanaged.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a real-time logs browser which is a piece of a simple software that either listens to files with logs or STDIN and prints it to the UI. Depending on the problem you're trying to solve there are a couple of tools that could be used for that purpose.
I'm the most advanced on the market currently would be [Logdy](https://logdy.dev) since you just download a precompiled binary, it can run with ANY input like:

```
$ tail -f file.log | logdy
```

Run it and you'll get all of the contents streamed to a Web UI. It also supports listening to multiple files and can even open a port and listen on TCP socket, check the [docs](https://logdy.dev/docs/quick-start) and blog for more use cases.

There are also other similar tools like:

- [log.io](http://logio.org/)
- [goaccess.io](https://goaccess.io/)
- [klogg](https://klogg.filimonov.dev/)
- [lnav](https://lnav.org/)